# How can I reload a image in kivy python

Tags: python, image, kivy

this is my script ...

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Image(source='go.jpg')

MyApp().run()
```

I won't to reload it becose the image is changing and I won't to see the new won all time

Answer (score 4):

you can use reload() the read the image from the disk again
this will reload even if the original data of the image is updated or changed

```
self.ids.image1.source = './Images/file.png'
self.ids.image1.reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your own widget class, and make the image an attribute, so you can reference it. Then use clock to schedule an interval method, to constantly reload the image.
In the example below, the `update_pic` method is executed once every second.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyImageWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyImageWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.image = Image(source='go.jpg')
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_pic,1)

    def update_pic(self,dt):
        self.image.reload()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyImageWidget()


MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Image.reload** method

```
def build(self):
    img = Image(source='go.jpg')
    Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: img.reload(), 0.2) #5 per second
    return img
```

Comment: wear do I hav to add it ?

Comment: You can call it in an interval as with the example that EL3PHANTEN wrote. I've updated my answer to include a short example