# change the background canvas kivy

Tags: python, image, canvas, kivy

I have a canvas background but I am trying to switch the back ground when a person his a correct button to move on to the next level. I am trying to do this all within one class. Is there a way to assign an image to a canvas rectangle and then on the press of a button the canvas image will change to a new source.

main.py

```
class MazeSolution(Screen):
    def CheckDoor1(self):
        if self.ids.door1.source == "correct":
            print("correct")
            self.ids.change.source = 's-curvee selection.png'
        else:
            print("incorrect")
```

main.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<MazeSolution>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                id: change
                source: 'selection grass.png'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"top": .8, "right": .75}
            size_hint: .5, .1
            text:
                "Door 1"
            source: "<random_name>"
            id: door1
            on_press:
                root.CheckDoor1()
```

Comment: .reload() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328063/how-can-i-reload-a-image-in-kivy-python

Comment: That solution is not working for me.

Comment: show minimal working code with this problem so wwe could run it and see problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think assigning `ids` within `canvas` instructions is supported. But you can accomplish the same thing by creating the `Rectangle` in `python`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class MazeSolution(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MazeSolution, self).__init__()
        # make the Rectangle here and save a reference to it
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.rect = Rectangle(source='selection grass.png')

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        # update Rectangle position when MazeSolution position changes
        self.rect.pos = self.pos

    def on_size(self, *args):
        # update Rectangle size when MazeSolution size changes
        self.rect.size = self.size

    def CheckDoor1(self):
        if self.ids.door1.source == "correct":
            print("correct")
            # use the saved reference to change the background 
            self.rect.source = 's-curvee selection.png'
        else:
            print("incorrect")

Builder.load_string('''
<MazeSolution>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"top": .8, "right": .75}
            size_hint: .5, .1
            text:
                "Door 1"
            source: "correct"
            id: door1
            on_press:
                root.CheckDoor1()
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MazeSolution())
        return sm

TestApp().run()
```

The `on_pos()` and `on_size()` methods perform the operations that `kv` would set up for you automatically, but must be set up manually since the `Rectangle` is not created in `kv`.